# Can I convert a String into a SINCall?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sinch

Im working with sinch and using firebase as my database and using its cloud functions to send notifications. Sending notifications are working fine but the `shouldSendPushNotifications` function but it never gets called so i can't add the  sinch payload to the notification data and I couldn't find anything on the internet of a solid working example so I gave up on that and decided to send the `SINcall` object to the database and the callee will retrieve it and answer that.

But the problem is that firebase only stores strings so when I retrieve the SINCall I stored i get an error `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x102096998) to '__ObjC.SINCall' (0x10209ab08)`. So is there a way to convert this to a SINCall so I can answer, decline, etc with it?

EDIT:
this is where i have my code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("USERINFO: \(userInfo["sin"]!)") <-- prints call: <SINCallImpl: 0x1c00f2600>
        let incomingCall = userInfo["sin"]!
        SINClientManager.shared.call = incomingCall as! SINCall <-- Error occurs
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please show us the code that is generating the error? If it is a lot of code, please try to come up with a small code sample that demonstrates the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @kismert i edited it to show where the error is generating

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data to the sinch client to set up  the call, you cant convert a string to a call.

```
   NSString* payload = [remotePush objectForKey:@"SIN"]; 
    // Get previously initiated Sinch client
    id<SINClient> client = [self sinchClient];
    id<SINNotificationResult> result = [client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:payload];
    if (result.isCall && result.callResult.isTimedOut) {
        // Present alert notifying about missed call
    } else if (!result.isValid) {
        // Handle error                
    }
```